# How do I fix error in installation of repoportal?

Tags: macos, docker, reportportal

I get an error when install repoportal.  First I download the components:

```
Steins-MacBook-Air:ATM steinkorsveien$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reportportal/reportportal/master/docker-compose.yml -o docker-compose.yml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6907  100  6907    0     0  12512      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12581
Steins-MacBook-Air:ATM steinkorsveien$ docker-compose up
Creating network "atm_default" with the default driver
Creating atm_ui_1            ... done
Creating atm_gateway_1       ... done
Creating atm_uat_1           ... done
Creating atm_postgres_1      ... done
Creating atm_minio_1         ... done
Creating atm_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Creating atm_rabbitmq_1      ... done
Creating atm_analyzer_1      ... done
Creating atm_index_1         ... done
Creating atm_db-scripts_1    ... done

ERROR: for api  Container "46cb34fca7b4" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

How do I fix this error?